# error: no device connected

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, boot-failure, boot-repair

I did a fresh install of 12.04 by usb and it went fine, worked on it for several days, but one day the browser crashed and i reset the machine, after that I get this error when i boot;

```
error: no device connected
error: no device connected
error: no device connected
error: no device connected
```

This comes after the BIOS confirmation, and it stays for about 30 seconds, then the grub menu comes and when I selected the default the screen becomes purple and stays like that for a whole Minuit. I thought maybe that is because I have 500GB HDD so i ran the boot-repair, It did nothing at all. I'm sure I did the boot-repair thing right, sorry I forgot the paste URL. If i reinstalled will this error persist.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu: USB, CDrom...?

Comment: after a usb install